# How do I silence FaceTime notifications without silencing others?

Tags: ios, ipad, notifications, facetime

With FaceTime on my iPad now notifying me of iPhone cellular calls, it is important to be able to silence FaceTime notifications, without silencing others (such as alarms or reminders); but there appears to be no way to do this.

How do I silence — not disable, just silence — FaceTime notifications without silencing others?

Answer (score 1):

Either Settings > Notifications > FaceTime > Sounds > None or I have misunderstood your question. Do you mean to prevent the notifications from making noise or just dismissing a notification after its begun?

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is configure the **Do Not Disturb** settings. You can set **Allow Calls From** to Everyone and then set **Silence** to either always or only while iPad is locked and you should still get notifications but they will be silenced.

Comment: That's the opposite of what the original poster asked.